# FFmpeg C++, H.264 parser build

Tags: c++, parsing, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I currently working on a project simulate webcam video transmission in C++, at sender side, I capture the raw webcame video with v4l2, encoded with FFmpeg, video file are put into an array and transmitted. And at decoder side, video data received to an array, decoded and play. The program works fine with codec_id **AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO**, but when I try replace it with **AV_CODEC_ID_H264**, some problem happen in decoding, please refer to [FFmpeg c++ H264 decoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406888/ffmpeg-c-h264-decoding-error). Some people suggest me to use parser but I have no idea how is a parse in ffmpeg looks like. Any simple example of how to build a parser for H.264 in FFmepg? I cannot find such tutorial in google.....

Comment: *some problem happen in decoding*; I'll see which ones in my crystal ball; brb.

Comment: sorry , please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406888/ffmpeg-c-h264-decoding-error