# Decoding a h264 (High) stream with OpenCV's ffmpeg on Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp

I am working with a video stream from an ip camera on Ubuntu 14.04. Everything was going great with a camera that has these parameters (from FFMPEG):

```
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 352x192, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

But then i changed to a newer camera, which has these parameters:

```
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

My C++ program uses OpenCV3 to process the stream. By default OpenCV uses ffmpeg to decode and display the stream with function VideoCapture.

```
VideoCapture vc;
vc.open(input_stream);
while ((vc >> frame), !frame.empty()) {
   *do work*
}
```

With the new camera stream i get errors like these (from ffmpeg):

```
[h264 @ 0x7c6980] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 41 38
[h264 @ 0x7c6980] error while decoding MB 41 38, bytestream (3572)
[h264 @ 0x7c6980] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 44
[h264 @ 0x7bc2c0] SEI type 25 truncated at 208
```

The image sometimes is glitched, sometimes completely frozen. However **on vlc it plays perfectly**. I installed the newest version (3.2.2) of ffmpeg player with

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
```

Now playing directly with ffplay (instead of launching from source code with OpenCV function VideoCapture), the stream plays better, but sometimes still displays warnings:

```
[NULL @ 0x7f834c008c00] SEI type 25 size 896 truncated at 320=1/1   
[h264 @ 0x7f834c0d5d20] SEI type 25 size 896 truncated at 319=1/1   
[rtsp @ 0x7f834c0008c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet   
[rtsp @ 0x7f834c0008c0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f834c094740] concealing 675 DC, 675 AC, 675 MV errors in P frame
```

Changing the camera hardware is not an option. The camera can be set to encode to h265 or mjpeg. When encoding to mjpeg it can output 5 fps, which is not enough. Decoding to a static video is not an option either, because i need to display real time results about the stream. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d) is a list of API backends that can be used in function VideoCapture. Maybe i should switch to some other decoder and player?
From my research i conclude that i have these options:

- Somehow get OpenCV to use libVlc instead of ffmpeg

One example of switching to vlc is [here](http://study.marearts.com/2015/09/opencv-rtsp-connection-using-vlc-library.html), but i don't understand it well enough to say if that is what i need. Or maybe i should be [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345495/ffmpeg-h264-parsing) the stream in code?

- Use vlc to preprocess the stream, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529620/opencv-and-network-cameras-or-how-to-spy-on-the-neighbors).

This is probably slow, which again is bad for real time results.
Any suggestions and coments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have mostly solved this issue.

- First i recompiled OpenCV with the newest version of ffmpeg manually installed on my device with the necessary settings.
- I checked the stream with VLC *tools* > *codec information* to check if the stream has corrupted frames, which it didn't.
- I lowered the stream resolution. This gave the biggest improvement.
- The last error that i'm still left with is

  [NULL @ 0x7f834c008c00] SEI type 25 size 896 truncated at 320=1/1
  [h264 @ 0x7f834c0d5d20] SEI type 25 size 896 truncated at 319=1/1

but it doesn't visibly damage the frames. I have not resolved the stream freezing issue however, but it has something to do with my code, not the software. If i can help anyone with similar problems, feel free to ask additional info.

Answer (score 3):

The errors are caused by packet loss since it uses RTP by default. You are seeing more errors now because you have switched to a higher bitrate input.

Append `?tcp` to your input, eg. `rtsp://*private*/media/video2?tcp` in OpenCV's `open` function to force TCP, assuming it's supported by your hardware and/or usage scenario.

Comment: Appended, but the stream still froze after ~10 seconds, which doesn't happen with the old camera stream, nor when palying straight from ffplay.

Comment: *when playing straight from  ffplay _that was compiled with h264 libs_.

Comment: @arvids if you need to test with `ffplay` use `-rtsp_transport tcp`

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem after 4 days research finaly i solved the problem easy by this code:

```
for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey();
        }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }
```