# FFmpeg C++ api decode h264 error

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, libav

I'm trying to use the C++ API of FFMpeg (version 20150526) under Windows using the prebuilt binaries to decode an h264 video file (*.ts).

I've written a very simple code that automatically detects the required codec from the file itself (and it is AV_CODEC_ID_H264, as expected).

Then I re-open the video file in read-binary mode and I read a fixed-size buffer of bytes from it and provide the read bytes to the decoder within a while-loop until the end of file. However when I call the function avcodec_decode_video2 a large amount of errors happen like the following ones:

[h264 @ 008df020] top block unavailable for requested intro mode at 34 0

[h264 @ 008df020] error while decoding MB 34 0, bytestream 3152

[h264 @ 008df020] decode_slice_header error

Sometimes the function avcodec_decode_video2 sets the value of got_picture_ptr to 1 and hence I expect to find a good frame. Instead, though all the computations are successful, when I view the decoded frame (using OpenCV only for visualization purposes) I see a gray one with some artifacts.

If I employ the same code to decode an *.avi file it works fine.

Reading the examples of FFMpeg I did not find a solution to my problem. I've also implemented the solution proposed in the simlar question [FFmpeg c++ H264 decoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406888/ffmpeg-c-h264-decoding-error) but it did not work.

Does anyone know where the error is?

Thank you in advance for any reply!

The code is the following [EDIT: code updated including the parser management]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif // __cplusplus
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavformat/avio.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libpostproc/postprocess.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // end extern "C".
#endif // __cplusplus

#define INBUF_SIZE  4096

void main()
{
    AVCodec*            l_pCodec;
    AVCodecContext*     l_pAVCodecContext;
    SwsContext*         l_pSWSContext;
    AVFormatContext*    l_pAVFormatContext;
    AVFrame*            l_pAVFrame;
    AVFrame*            l_pAVFrameBGR;
    AVPacket            l_AVPacket;
    AVPacket            l_AVPacket_out;
    AVStream*           l_pStream;
    AVCodecParserContext*   l_pParser;
    FILE*               l_pFile_in;
    FILE*               l_pFile_out;
    std::string         l_sFile;
    int                 l_iResult;
    int                 l_iFrameCount;
    int                 l_iGotFrame;
    int                 l_iBufLength;
    int                 l_iParsedBytes;
    int                 l_iPts;
    int                 l_iDts;
    int                 l_iPos;
    int                 l_iSize;
    int                 l_iDecodedBytes;
    uint8_t             l_auiInBuf[INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    uint8_t*            l_pData;
    cv::Mat             l_cvmImage;

    l_pCodec = NULL;
    l_pAVCodecContext = NULL;
    l_pSWSContext = NULL;
    l_pAVFormatContext = NULL;
    l_pAVFrame = NULL;
    l_pAVFrameBGR = NULL;
    l_pParser = NULL;
    l_pStream = NULL;
    l_pFile_in = NULL;
    l_pFile_out = NULL;
    l_iPts = 0;
    l_iDts = 0;
    l_iPos = 0;
    l_pData = NULL;

    l_sFile = "myvideo.ts";

    avdevice_register_all();
    avfilter_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    l_pAVFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    l_iResult = avformat_open_input(&l_pAVFormatContext,
                                    l_sFile.c_str(),
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL);

    if (l_iResult >= 0)
    {
        l_iResult = avformat_find_stream_info(l_pAVFormatContext, NULL);

        if (l_iResult >= 0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<l_pAVFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
            {
                if (l_pAVFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type ==
                        AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                {
                    l_pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(
                                l_pAVFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_id);

                    l_pStream = l_pAVFormatContext->streams[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    av_init_packet(&l_AVPacket);
    av_init_packet(&l_AVPacket_out);

    memset(l_auiInBuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);

    if (l_pCodec)
    {
        l_pAVCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(l_pCodec);

        l_pParser = av_parser_init(l_pAVCodecContext->codec_id);

        if (l_pParser)
        {
            av_register_codec_parser(l_pParser->parser);
        }

        if (l_pAVCodecContext)
        {
            if (l_pCodec->capabilities & CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
            {
                l_pAVCodecContext->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;
            }

            l_iResult = avcodec_open2(l_pAVCodecContext, l_pCodec, NULL);

            if (l_iResult >= 0)
            {
                l_pFile_in = fopen(l_sFile.c_str(), "rb");

                if (l_pFile_in)
                {
                    l_pAVFrame = av_frame_alloc();
                    l_pAVFrameBGR = av_frame_alloc();

                    if (l_pAVFrame)
                    {
                        l_iFrameCount = 0;

                        avcodec_get_frame_defaults(l_pAVFrame);

                        while (1)
                        {
                            l_iBufLength = fread(l_auiInBuf,
                                                 1,
                                                 INBUF_SIZE,
                                                 l_pFile_in);

                            if (l_iBufLength == 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                l_pData = l_auiInBuf;
                                l_iSize = l_iBufLength;

                                while (l_iSize > 0)
                                {
                                    if (l_pParser)
                                    {
                                        l_iParsedBytes = av_parser_parse2(
                                                    l_pParser,
                                                    l_pAVCodecContext,
                                                    &l_AVPacket_out.data,
                                                    &l_AVPacket_out.size,
                                                    l_pData,
                                                    l_iSize,
                                                    l_AVPacket.pts,
                                                    l_AVPacket.dts,
                                                    AV_NOPTS_VALUE);

                                        if (l_iParsedBytes <= 0)
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }

                                        l_AVPacket.pts = l_AVPacket.dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
                                        l_AVPacket.pos = -1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        l_AVPacket_out.data = l_pData;
                                        l_AVPacket_out.size = l_iSize;
                                    }

                                    l_iDecodedBytes =
                                            avcodec_decode_video2(
                                                l_pAVCodecContext,
                                                l_pAVFrame,
                                                &l_iGotFrame,
                                                &l_AVPacket_out);

                                    if (l_iDecodedBytes >= 0)
                                    {
                                        if (l_iGotFrame)
                                        {
                                            l_pSWSContext = sws_getContext(
                                                        l_pAVCodecContext->width,
                                                        l_pAVCodecContext->height,
                                                        l_pAVCodecContext->pix_fmt,
                                                        l_pAVCodecContext->width,
                                                        l_pAVCodecContext->height,
                                                        AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                                        SWS_BICUBIC,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        NULL);

                                            if (l_pSWSContext)
                                            {
                                                l_iResult = avpicture_alloc(
                                                            reinterpret_cast<AVPicture*>(l_pAVFrameBGR),
                                                            AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                                            l_pAVFrame->width,
                                                            l_pAVFrame->height);

                                                l_iResult = sws_scale(
                                                            l_pSWSContext,
                                                            l_pAVFrame->data,
                                                            l_pAVFrame->linesize,
                                                            0,
                                                            l_pAVCodecContext->height,
                                                            l_pAVFrameBGR->data,
                                                            l_pAVFrameBGR->linesize);

                                                if (l_iResult > 0)
                                                {
                                                    l_cvmImage = cv::Mat(
                                                                l_pAVFrame->height,
                                                                l_pAVFrame->width,
                                                                CV_8UC3,
                                                                l_pAVFrameBGR->data[0],
                                                            l_pAVFrameBGR->linesize[0]);

                                                    if (l_cvmImage.empty() == false)
                                                    {
                                                        cv::imshow("image", l_cvmImage);
                                                        cv::waitKey(10);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            l_iFrameCount++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    l_pData += l_iParsedBytes;
                                    l_iSize -= l_iParsedBytes;
                                }
                            }

                        } // end while(1).
                    }

                    fclose(l_pFile_in);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: The following is the final code that solves my problem, thanks to the suggestions of Ronald.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif // __cplusplus
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavformat/avio.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libpostproc/postprocess.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // end extern "C".
#endif // __cplusplus

void main()
{
    AVCodec*            l_pCodec;
    AVCodecContext*     l_pAVCodecContext;
    SwsContext*         l_pSWSContext;
    AVFormatContext*    l_pAVFormatContext;
    AVFrame*            l_pAVFrame;
    AVFrame*            l_pAVFrameBGR;
    AVPacket            l_AVPacket;
    std::string         l_sFile;
    uint8_t*            l_puiBuffer;
    int                 l_iResult;
    int                 l_iFrameCount;
    int                 l_iGotFrame;
    int                 l_iDecodedBytes;
    int                 l_iVideoStreamIdx;
    int                 l_iNumBytes;
    cv::Mat             l_cvmImage;

    l_pCodec = NULL;
    l_pAVCodecContext = NULL;
    l_pSWSContext = NULL;
    l_pAVFormatContext = NULL;
    l_pAVFrame = NULL;
    l_pAVFrameBGR = NULL;
    l_puiBuffer = NULL;

    l_sFile = "myvideo.ts";

    av_register_all();

    l_iResult = avformat_open_input(&l_pAVFormatContext,
                                    l_sFile.c_str(),
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL);

    if (l_iResult >= 0)
    {
        l_iResult = avformat_find_stream_info(l_pAVFormatContext, NULL);

        if (l_iResult >= 0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<l_pAVFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
            {
                if (l_pAVFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type ==
                        AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                {
                    l_iVideoStreamIdx = i;

                    l_pAVCodecContext =
                            l_pAVFormatContext->streams[l_iVideoStreamIdx]->codec;

                    if (l_pAVCodecContext)
                    {
                        l_pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(l_pAVCodecContext->codec_id);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (l_pCodec && l_pAVCodecContext)
    {
        l_iResult = avcodec_open2(l_pAVCodecContext, l_pCodec, NULL);

        if (l_iResult >= 0)
        {
            l_pAVFrame = av_frame_alloc();
            l_pAVFrameBGR = av_frame_alloc();

            l_iNumBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                             l_pAVCodecContext->width,
                                             l_pAVCodecContext->height);

            l_puiBuffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(l_iNumBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

            avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)l_pAVFrameBGR,
                           l_puiBuffer,
                           PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                           l_pAVCodecContext->width,
                           l_pAVCodecContext->height);

            l_pSWSContext = sws_getContext(
                        l_pAVCodecContext->width,
                        l_pAVCodecContext->height,
                        l_pAVCodecContext->pix_fmt,
                        l_pAVCodecContext->width,
                        l_pAVCodecContext->height,
                        AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                        SWS_BICUBIC,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        NULL);

            while (av_read_frame(l_pAVFormatContext, &l_AVPacket) >= 0)
            {
                if (l_AVPacket.stream_index == l_iVideoStreamIdx)
                {
                    l_iDecodedBytes = avcodec_decode_video2(
                                l_pAVCodecContext,
                                l_pAVFrame,
                                &l_iGotFrame,
                                &l_AVPacket);

                    if (l_iGotFrame)
                    {
                        if (l_pSWSContext)
                        {
                            l_iResult = sws_scale(
                                        l_pSWSContext,
                                        l_pAVFrame->data,
                                        l_pAVFrame->linesize,
                                        0,
                                        l_pAVCodecContext->height,
                                        l_pAVFrameBGR->data,
                                        l_pAVFrameBGR->linesize);

                            if (l_iResult > 0)
                            {
                                l_cvmImage = cv::Mat(
                                            l_pAVFrame->height,
                                            l_pAVFrame->width,
                                            CV_8UC3,
                                            l_pAVFrameBGR->data[0],
                                        l_pAVFrameBGR->linesize[0]);

                                if (l_cvmImage.empty() == false)
                                {
                                    cv::imshow("image", l_cvmImage);
                                    cv::waitKey(1);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        l_iFrameCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you use ffmpeg on it, no errors?

Comment: Yes. of course. Even if I use ffplay the video is decoded without errors and everything is as expected.

Comment: feels as if it's losing bits somehow...hmm...gl!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never using the l_pParser object, or in other words, you're not using a H264 parser, you're just sending raw file data into the decoder without proper NAL packetization. Please read the [frame parsing API docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__parsing.html) to figure out how to use the parser.

Comment: Thank you Ronald for your suggestions. Unfortunately even with the parser (as you also suggested in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406888/ffmpeg-c-h264-decoding-error) I get the same large amount of errors and the frame is not properly decoded (I get the same gray image with some artifacts). I have updated the code in the original question including the parser management. Thank you very much again for your support!

Comment: Your code works for me, the only comment I have is that in between your calls to av_parser_parse2() and avcodec_decode_video2(), you should check whether l_iParsedBytes <= 0, and if so, break out of the loop. But even without that check, the code runs fine for me on 2 test files.

Comment: Actually, wait a minute, sorry for just noticing now, but this code only works for raw H264 (annexb) files. Your input file is a .ts file. Parsers can't read .ts files, just parse raw h264/annexb content. For .ts, you need a full-blown .ts demuxer, which you'll find in libavformat.

Comment: Many thanks Ronald. I've tried my code with different files but also with other video formats I get lots of errors and the resulting image is always the same gray one. I am not able to decode almost any video with my code. I've tried with *.mpg (codec mpeg2video), *.mov (mpeg4), *.avi (mpeg4). Only some (very few) avi files are properly decoded. Could you please post me a link where I can find support for the full-blown *.ts demuxer you mentioned? I place the updated version of my code (with few modifications) in the original question.

Comment: See e.g. http://linux.amazingdev.com/blog/archives/2011/09/28/tutorial01.c and look for the call to avformat_open_input(), av_find_stream_info () and av_read_frame() (and related code) and use that instead of av_parser_parse2(). Full API docs here: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html

Comment: Great! The tutorial01.c code you provide (with very few modifications to be compliant with the latest version of ffmpeg) works fine on all my test videos! I'll check my code comparing it to tutorial01.c and I'll post to final code original question as soon as it works, so that I can mark your answer as "accepted". Thanks a lot again.